# Passport.js missing credentials

Tags: express, authentication, passport.js, express-session, passport-local

I am trying to use passport.js for authentification. My website will be private, so the user doesn't need to register to enter, he will go to a login page, chose his name among a list (with  HTML tag), and will enter his birthday date as a password.

When I'm trying to login with a wrong or good password, I get an error in my flash message : missing credentials. I have search a lot but every solutions on Internet don't work for me...

Here is my code :

*passport-config.js*

```
let md5 = require('md5');
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const peoples = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"];
const passwords = {
    "User1": md5("2004"),
    "User2": md5("2001"),
    "User3": md5("1971"),
    "User4": md5("1969")
}
let user;

function initialize(passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
        function(username, password, done) {

            user = peoples.find(people => people === username);

            if(user === undefined || user === null) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "This user doesn't exist" });
            }

            if(md5(password) === passwords[username]) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect pasword" });
            }
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.username); // see PS
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, peoples.find(people => people === user));
    });
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

*server.js*

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let passport = require('passport');
let md5 = require('md5');
let session = require('express-session');
let flash = require('express-flash');
let initializePassport = require('./passport-config.js');
initializePassport(passport);

app.use(session({
    secret: md5("test"),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const peoples = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"];

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs", {
        peoples: peoples
    });
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

The website also always redirect me to /login, whatever my password is.

Can you help me please ? Thanks !

PS : I would also like to know what is the "user" param inside the passport.serializeUser function. I have followed lots of tutorials and docs but can't know what is this. I would also add that I can't console.log something inside the function inserted in the LocalStrategy instance.